# Generate 3 different random number in Python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am beginner in python. I want to generate 3 set of different number within specified range using `numpy.random.randint` in python3. (F.Y.I -> Want to implement K-Means)

I am using this code

```
# Number of clusters
k = 3
# X coordinates of random centroids
C_x = np.random.randint(38.8, 39.4, size=k)
# Y coordinates of random centroids
C_y = np.random.randint(-77.5,-76.5, size=k)
C = np.array(list(zip(C_x, C_y)), dtype=np.float32)
print(C)
```

But each iteration gives me same set of values

```
[[ 38. -77.]
 [ 38. -77.]
 [ 38. -77.]]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your only integer in the range 38 (inclusive) and 39 (non inclusive) is 38, that's why you always get 38, same for the second ranges - your ranges do not allow anything else as they are not inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

The [`randint()` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) operates on *integers*; your floats are floored to integers before taking the random value. Because the second values is *exclusive*, you are producing a range of just *one* value each.

Either pass in *integers* for the low and high values (and pick a larger range), or use one of the [distribution functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html#distributions). The [`numpy.random.uniform()` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html#distributions) is fine for your needs, I presume?

```
>>> C_x = np.random.uniform(38.8, 39.4, size=k)
>>> C_y = np.random.uniform(-77.5,-76.5, size=k)
>>> np.array(list(zip(C_x, C_y)), dtype=np.float32)
array([[ 39.04865646, -76.83393097],
       [ 39.06672668, -76.70361328],
       [ 39.35120773, -77.00741577]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `numpy.random.uniform`

```
# Number of clusters
k = 3
# X coordinates of random centroids
C_x = np.random.uniform(38.8, 39.4, size=k)
# Y coordinates of random centroids
C_y = np.random.uniform(-77.5,-76.5, size=k)
C = np.array(list(zip(C_x, C_y)), dtype=np.float32)
print(C)
```

and it worked.

```
[[ 38.88471603 -77.37638855]
 [ 38.99485779 -76.99333954]
 [ 38.97389603 -77.27649689]]
```